# Converting Standard C# to MonoTouch compliant code

Tags: c#, bitmap, xamarin.ios

I need to convert the following method from C# to MonoTouch compliant code:

```
private WritableBitMap CreateBitMapWPF(RGBPaletteRecord rgbPalette, double dpi)
        {
            WritableBitMap bitmapImage = null;

            try
            {
                bitmapImage = new WritableBitMap(TileRecord.PixelWidth, TileRecord.PixelHight, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Rgb24, BitmapPalettes.Halftone256);
              //  int nStride = (bitmapImage.PixelWidth * bitmapImage.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
                int nStride = (bitmapImage.PixelWidth * bitmapImage.Format.BitsPerPixel  / 8);
                System.Windows.Int32Rect rect = new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, TileRecord.PixelWidth, TileRecord.PixelHight);

                byte[] data = GetBytes(rgbPalette);

                bitmapImage.WritePixels(rect, data, nStride, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            //// temp write to file to test         
            //using (FileStream stream5 = new FileStream(@"C:\test.bmp", FileMode.Create))
            //{

            //    BitmapEncoder encoder5 = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            //    encoder5.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
            //    encoder5.Save(stream5);
            //    stream5.Close();
            //}

            //
            return bitmapImage;

        }
```

I'm not asking for someone to do the actual conversion, but I'm wondering what the best approach to take would be when converting this code?  Should I focus on converting to use the MonoTouch libraries?  Standard System libraries?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Tysin

**EDIT;** Basically the purpose of this conversion is that I have these C# classes that perform a set of functions to do with bitmapped images, I'm using MonoTouch as I need to use these files in an iPhone application.

Comment: it really depends on what its trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what the best approach to take would be when converting this code?

It depends on your goals and application(s). If you plan to share code across products / versions then you better have an API that abstract the platform details and separate code for each platform.

> Should I focus on converting to use the MonoTouch libraries?

The WPF API is not supported on iOS (or MonoTouch). So you're closest *bet* is to look at the iOS API that MonoTouch provides (i.e. look at what's already available before looking at 3rd party libraries).

You'll find similar features by using iOS **CoreGraphics** (which in general is pretty similar to the older `System.Drawing` model). For bitmap image you should read the documentation of the `CGImage` type.

- [MonoTouch's CGImage documentation (C#)](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGImage)
- [Apple CGImage documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should also look at this project :

https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics

made by Frank Krueger (gg!) it enable you to share the same basic graphics code between platform. It's an API that abstract the details implementation of each platform. For now it seems to be limited only to basic graphics (like fillrect and so forth....